# Memory leak — probably due to block out-of-scope

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I have a memory leak that involves blocks, and I think it's related to this — stripped — code segment. I think the problem is that the block definitions runs out of scope before I pass the tapCbk to scrollLayerItem.

I guess I can copy the block at each definition and release it at the end, but that seems error prone. I would prefer to keep the switch, because I do more stuff in these case blocks. I use MRC.

Is there a better way to solve this?

```
void (^tapCbk)(void) = nil;

switch (state)
{
  case INVITED:
    tapCbk =
    ^{
       :
    };
    break;

  case SOMETHING_OTHER:
    tapCbk =
    ^{
       :
    };
    break; 

  : // Lots of more cases, and a default
}

ScrollLayerItem *item = [ScrollLayerItem itemWithNode:scrollLayerItemNode
                                               tapCbk:tapCbk];
```

Comment: "Is there a better way to solve this?" Yes: use ARC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make a copy of your block and autorelease it before passing it outside of the function in which it's created:

```
tapCbk = [[tapCbk copy] autorelease];
```

Or, just use ARC.

Comment: Of cause! Then it will be less error prone, as the copy and autorelease is at the same place. Nice!

Comment: @FreeNickname No, because unlike other objects, blocks are stack variables. They must be copied. See https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-08-14-practical-blocks.html

Comment: And also http://blog.refractalize.org/post/10476042560/copy-vs-retain-for-objective-c-blocks

Comment: "You have to make a copy of your block and autorelease it before passing it outside of the function in which it's created:" Not true, and not in the case here. You do not have to copy the block before passing it to a parameter of block type. The naming of the method with "tapCbk:" indicates this parameter is block type. Under memory management conventions, a function that takes a parameter of block type will take responsibility for copying it if it in turn needs to store it.

Comment: "Or, just use ARC." ARC does not guarantee that the block is copied in the case where you pass the block to a parameter of non-block type. You still should copy it in that case.

Comment: Both of your comments are correct, @newacct, although the second is outside the scope of this question.

Answer (score 0):

A block created by a block literal is only valid for the duration of the local scope of the block literal. In this case, the local scope of those block literals is the body of that `switch` statement. You store the block in a variable that is used after the body of the `switch` statement, so you need to copy the block before it leaves the body of the `switch` statement.

If you did not have a `switch`, and instead created the block at the top level, e.g. `void (^tapCbk)(void) = ^{ ... };`, then you wouldn't have to copy it. If you still have problems in this case, then there is something wrong in your `+[ScrollLayerItem itemWithNode:tapCbk:tapCbk]` method.